# How to set data object to widget that doesn't have setData() method

Tags: python, pyqt

I need to connect data object (class instance) to `QLabel` widget that doesn't have setData() method. Is there a way to extend QLabel so it supports data attachment?

Comment: @three_pineapples Not necessary — see my answer.

Comment: I know it isn't necessary, but I would consider duck punching/monkey patching poor form. Subclassing is the preferred method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest subclassing. While @BlackJack's answer will work, it is generally considered poor form to "duck punch"/"monkey patch" as you open yourself up to problems. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch#Pitfalls)

> Carelessly written or poorly documented monkey patches can lead to problems:
>
> - They can lead to upgrade problems when the patch makes assumptions about the patched object that are no longer true; if the product you have changed changes with a new release it may very well break your patch. For this reason monkey patches are often made conditional, and only applied if appropriate.
> - If two modules attempt to monkey patch the same method, one of them (whichever one runs last) "wins" and the other patch has no effect, unless monkey patches are written with a pattern like alias_method_chain.
> - They create a discrepancy between the original source code on disk and the observed behaviour that can be very confusing to anyone unaware of the patches' existence.
>
> Even if monkey patching isn't used, some see a problem with the availability of the feature, since the ability to use monkey patching in a programming language is incompatible with enforcing strong encapsulation, as required by the object-capability model, between objects.

As such, subclassing is the preferred approach. Something like this, for example:

```
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QLabel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._data = None

    def data(self):
        return self._data

    def setData(self, data):
        self._data = data
```

This then matches Qt syntax of other classes.

You could also extend it to support storing data for multiple roles (like some other Qt classes)

```
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QLabel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._data = {}

    def data(self, role = Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role in self._data:
            return self._data[role]
        return None

    def setData(self, data, role = Qt.DisplayRole):
        self._data[role] = data
```

Obviously this is only for use by your Python code (Qt won't use it).

Comment: I get the second example but the first is quite unpythonic as it uses trivial getters and setters.  Python's not Java.

Comment: @BlackJack The point was not to be Pythonic but to be consistent with PyQt, which is a wrapper around a c++ GUI toolkit (Qt).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to just assign the data to an attribute?

```
In [2]: from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

In [3]: import sys

In [4]: app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

In [5]: label = QtGui.QLabel('Test')

In [6]: label.answer = 42

In [7]: label.answer
Out[7]: 42
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamic setProperty method to hide extra information inside Qt objects.

```
self.myqlabel.setProperty("answer", 42)
```

Then use the property method to retrieve the information later:

```
value = self.myqlabel.property("answer")
```

What is also nice about this technique.. you can store multiple pieces of data, just change the property string to whatever you want:

```
self.myqlabel.setProperty("name", "bruno mars")
```

Not sure, but this may be a Qt5 feature?